# Applying Domain Rules from SSIS

Tags: ssis, data-quality-services

I have Created 15 Domain rules in Data Quality Service on Name Domain. Now I want to apply all rules for data cleansing purpose from SQL Server Integration Services(SSIS). I want to apply this 15 rules one after one(Step by Step). How can i achieve it from SSIS? Can anyone Help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the [SSIS DQS Matching Transformation](https://ssisdqsmatching.codeplex.com/) available in Codeplex. The transformation is described in  [Automating the Data Matching Process](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dqs/archive/2013/06/25/automating-the-data-matching-process-in-sql-server-data-quality-services-dqs.aspx) at the [DQS team's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dqs/).

The source code isn't complex so you could use it as a base to create your own transformations if you want

Comment: i have gone through it. will it make cleansing through domain rules one after another?

Comment: I have made SSIS project in which i took data cleansing transformation but it is not applying any rule as it is active in domain management. what is the problem?